# Angluar 12: I can't do ng serve --open

Tags: angular, terminal

I don't know if this is an error but every time I do `ng serve --open` in my terminal I always received this message:

```
D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public>ng serve --open
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0,
but Angular version 12.2.5 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/
```

I only use angular 12

What I've tried so far

```
ng --version
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@12.1.0
ng --version
```

Just like the answer below, I tried to do `npm cache clean --force` but I get this from my terminal:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
```

I also tried to go to `%appdata%` and delete the npm-cache folder and run `npm cache clean --force` again, but I still get this:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
```

and when I tried to `ng-serve` it I still get the message (above)

Comment: You need to downgrade your globally installed Angular CLI version (assuming you didn't manually upgrade the project-specific version.)

Comment: what if I downgrade it? Will I lose my project?

Comment: Try this to downgrade your angular cli.
npm install -g @angular/cli@12.0.3

Comment: No, you will not. What Angular CLI version is printed when you run `ng --version` __outside__ of your project folder? It should print something like 13.x.y. If that is the case you can downgrade via `npm install -g @angular/cli@12.x`

Comment: one more question should I execute this command inside my project folder?

Comment: I tried to run ng --version outside my folder and inside my project folder but the version of my angular is both Angular CLI: 12.2.5

Comment: I've tried what y'all suggest and nothing is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

```
ng --version
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@12.1.0
ng --version
```

you can also try installing other versions like 12.2 or the latest 12.* using the above command. For reference, I have mentioned 12.1.0

---

If you are getting disabled error, do this:

delete it manually: type in windows search - run - %appdata% - delete npm-cache folder
Reinstall the node that should fix everything

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Run above command only after deleting npm-cache folder

Comment: I've tried it but when I do the command npm cache clean --force I received this: 
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

Comment: in run dialogue of windows type %appdata%  and then find npm-cache folder delete it @Biax20

Comment: Updated answer @Biax20

Comment: delete the entire folder?

Comment: hi i deleted the folder I still got this npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

Comment: where should I excute this command npm install -g npm@latest ?

Comment: should I execute inside my project folder?

Comment: Anywhere would work. -g mean it is global so it will be installed / uninstalled at your MAC/PC level

Comment: so If i do this inside my project folder I would only delete what inside and It would not touch my other angular projects?

Comment: Yes.. you simply uninstall and install. It doesn't; affect any other projects. @Biax20

Comment: Hi, I think I fix it but every time I serve it takes a lot of time. I created a question of it, maybe you can help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244804/angular-12-ng-serve-open-takes-too-long-and-have-a-lot-of-message here is the link