# Angular 12: ng serve --open takes too long and have a lot of message

Tags: terminal, angular-cli

So I have a previous problem with my angular 12 you can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70242823/angluar-12-i-cant-do-ng-serve-open?noredirect=1#comment124170410_70242823) for reference

So I kinda fix it now and I can do `ng serve --open`, but I got this message, maybe an error and it never serve or show the output its just it takes a lot of time.

ERROR:

```
D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public>ng serve public
⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...(node:12832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.4.2 and <4.5.0 but 4.3.5 was found instead.
    at checkVersion (file:///D:/3rdYR/AppDev/bigProject/public/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/index.js:17440:11)
    at verifySupportedTypeScriptVersion (file:///D:/3rdYR/AppDev/bigProject/public/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/index.js:17444:3)
    at new NgtscProgram (file:///D:/3rdYR/AppDev/bigProject/public/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/index.js:17594:7)
    at AngularWebpackPlugin.updateAotProgram (D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:321:32)
    at D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:198:24
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1054:30)
    at D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1099:29
    at eval (eval at create (D:\3rdYR\AppDev\bigProject\public\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:12832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12832) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
```

Right now it is still generating but it is like going on like that for 10 minutes at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong typescript version installed in your Project.
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.4.2 and <4.5.0 but 4.3.5 was found instead.

Change in your Package Json your Typescript version to 4.4.2 and npm install than try ng serve again :)

Comment: Can you please explain it more? I don't quite understand it?

Comment: why do I need to install npm again?

Comment: it worked thanks a LOT